# Pass An Azure Key Vault Secret To The Azure Databricks Spark Submit Job Using Parameters

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-keyvault

How to pass an Azure key vault secret to the Azure Databricks spark submit job using parameters?
I tried everything:

1. Set into parameters: "--conf","spark.secret={{secrets/secret-scope/key}}"
2. Set into spark config: spark.secret {{secrets/secret-scope/key}}
3. I've tried to use "dbutils" at spark parameters

Got "Unexpected token" error in all cases

I expect to pass a key from Azure Key Vault to the Azure Databricks Spark Submit job config file